# How to use a loop to execute result in different arrays of different id

Tags: php

I have produced a result from the following query as shown below.Now the result I got is an array in which all the results are stored according to 'portfolio_id'... I need to print different array of results for different portfolio_id. How is it possible?

For example when portfolio_id is 1 it will produce a frame of 9images ,portfolio_id is 18 it must produce another frame of 9 images...

```
$portfolio_item_query=$ilance->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "portfolio AS p,
                                        " . DB_PREFIX . "portfolio_images AS pi,
                                          " . DB_PREFIX . "users AS u,
                                        " . DB_PREFIX . "subscription_user AS su,
                                        " . DB_PREFIX . "portfolio_items AS it
                                       WHERE p.portfolio_id = it.portfolio_id
                                       AND u.user_id = p.user_id 
                                      AND it.id = pi.portfolio_item_id 
                                     AND it.portfolio_id='".$portfolio['portfolio_id']."'
                                      GROUP BY it.id ORDER BY it.id ASC LIMIT 0,9");
                            $num_rows=$ilance->db->num_rows($portfolio_item_query); 
                            if ($num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($portfolio_item = $ilance->db->fetch_array($portfolio_item_query))
            {  
            $portfolio_html.='<li><img height="57" width="57" src="images/portfolio_uploads/orig_'.$portfolio_item['image'].'"></a></li>';

                }
                    echo $portfolio_html;
         }
```

Comment: What is a "frame"?  A new `<ul>`?

Comment: ya , the result is showing ,but now all results of different portfolio_id are in one array ....

Comment: So, you want a new `ul` for each `portfolio_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the entire data set, keeping track of the `portfolio_id` of each row.  Then, each time the `portfoio_id` changes, start a new list.

If I'm understanding correctly, this should help.  Here's how you could separate a generic set of images into different unordered lists using `group_id` to define groups:

```
// select the entire set, group by whichever field defines your groups
$result = mysql_query("SELECT image_path FROM portfolio ORDER BY group_id");

// the group_id associated with the currently growing <ul>
$current_id = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
    $group_id = $row['group_id'];

    // the first list
    if (is_null($current_id))
    {
        $current_id = $group_id;
        echo "<ul>\n";
    }

    // if a new group_id is encountered, close the list and start a new one
    elseif ($group_id != $current_id)
    {
        $current_id = $group_id;
        echo "</ul>\n\n<ul>\n";
    }

    echo "<li><image src=\"" . $row['image_path'] . "\"></li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```

The table looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM portfolio;
+------------+----------+
| image_path | group_id |
+------------+----------+
| a.png      |        1 |
| b.png      |        3 |
| c.png      |        4 |
| d.png      |        3 |
| e.png      |        3 |
| f.png      |        1 |
| g.png      |        4 |
+------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the output of the above program looks like this:

```
<ul> 
<li><image src="a.png"></li> 
<li><image src="f.png"></li> 
</ul> 

<ul> 
<li><image src="b.png"></li> 
<li><image src="d.png"></li> 
<li><image src="e.png"></li> 
</ul> 

<ul> 
<li><image src="c.png"></li> 
<li><image src="g.png"></li> 
</ul>
```